# Retrieving only the date part of a datetime column in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am a starter in Django/Python.

I have a model `MyModel`. It has many fields of `datetime`, `char`, `integer` types. Now, I want a values list which has values of the datetime fields containing only the date parts.

I have tried using the dates function [reference] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#dates), but it works only with one field. I have multiple datetime fields and all have to be retrieved in the required format.

Basically, I want a Django equivalent of :

`select stringfield1, date(datefield1), integerfield1, date(datefield2) from mymodel;` (PostGreSQL)

Is this even possible? If it is, how should I proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Django has a builtin way of doing this. You could use [`itertools.imap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) to lazily convert the fields in question into `date` objects:

```
from itertools import imap
values = MyModel.objects.values_list('stringfield1', 'datefield1', 
                                       'integerfield1', 'datefield2')
values = imap(lambda (s, d1, i, d2): (s, d1.date(), i, d2.date()), values)
```

(But note that after this you're not dealing with a `ValuesListQuerySet` anymore but with an `itertools.imap` object.)

Comment: Thanx a lot for your effort. I have to pass the generated queryset further as part of a JSON. So, have to keep it as a list of values as returned by a queryset. Can I specifically do the same with this?

Comment: Not directly -- if you just intend to use `json.dump` or something, it doesn't really matter if you use `itertools.imap` -- the builtin `map` will do fine and return a list.